# WordPress enqueue stylesheet not working

Tags: php, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I'm new to working with PHP in WordPress and I was hoping to add a stylesheet to a specific page.

In functions.php I made a function that I thought would add my stylesheet called 'testPost.css' if the page name is 'test2'. In this function I also added an alert box to test if the function works at all.

When I click on 'page2' I do see my alert box but I do not see my new styles. I printed `get_stylesheet_uri()` in my alert box and see that it is pointing to "localhost/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/style.css". This is not what I wanted; I expected to link to my 'testPost.css' instead. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and the correct way to achieve what I want?

### functions.php

```
function lindsay_script(){
    if(is_page('test2')) 
    {   
        $message = get_stylesheet_uri();
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

        wp_enqueue_style( 'twentythirteen-testPost', get_stylesheet_uri().'/testPost.css' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lindsay_script');
```

Comment: you can use var_dump to dump a PHP variable, like in     var_dump($message);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`get_stylesheet_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri) points to `style.css`.

Assuming that the CSS file you made is **in the same directory** as `style.css`, replace `get_stylesheet_uri` with [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) and you should be good to go.